# REST List<Entity> return causing errors

Tags: java, web-services, list, rest

I have tried for two hours to try and get a return value from a REST web service which was generated but Netbeans but throws an error what ever I try. 
The generated code from netbeans is

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Person> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

When I create a client I get this generated code

```
public <T> T findAll_XML(Class<T> responseType) throws UniformInterfaceException {
     WebResource resource = webResource;
     return  resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
}
```

I have tried a number of ways to call this and after a lot of surfing decided this should do the trick but it doesn't.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonRESTClient prc = new PersonRESTClient();
    Person person = prc.find_XML(Person.class, "100");
    System.out.println(person.getFirstname() + " " + person.getSecondname()); //THIS WORKS!!
   GenericType<List<Person>> gType = new GenericType<List<Person>>(){};
   List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) prc.findAll_XML(gType.getClass());
   for (Person p : persons) {
       System.out.println(person.getFirstname() + " " + person.getSecondname());
   }

}
```

the error I get is

> Mar 07, 2013 2:23:31 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse
>   getEntity SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class
>   restexample2client.RestExample2Client$1, and Java type class
>   restexample2client.RestExample2Client$1, and MIME media type
>   application/xml was not found Mar 07, 2013 2:23:31 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity SEVERE: The
>   registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type
>   are: application/xml ->
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$App
>   */* ->   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body
>   reader for Java class restexample2client.RestExample2Client$1, and
>   Java type class restexample2client.RestExample2Client$1, and MIME
>   media type application/xml was not found  at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517)
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:684)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
>     at
>   com.carnabygaming.rest.service.client.EnterpriseRESTClient.findAll_XML(EnterpriseRESTClient.java:47)
>     at
>   restexample2client.RestExample2Client.main(RestExample2Client.java:32)

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong? Single Object generated code works just fine.
I have just noticed that when i do a test the method does not appear in the web page. Still need help please.

Answer (score 6):

Yea, you need to provide an overloaded variant of your client method that accepts a supertype token (`GenericType`). Right now your second client call is *literally* attempting to deserialize the response data as the class `GenericType<List<Person>>`, which is not what you want. So, first, define an overloaded method on your client that accepts a supertype token:

```
public <T> T findAll_XML(GenericType<T> superType) throws UniformInterfaceException {
     WebResource resource = webResource;
     return  resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(superType);
}
```

And use it in your client as so:

```
GenericType<List<Person>> gType = new GenericType<List<Person>>() {};
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) prc.findAll_XML(gType);
for (Person p : persons) {
    System.out.println(person.getFirstname() + " "
            + person.getSecondname());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was one 100% what I needed. I wonder why I could find no mention of this on the Netbeans site. Still thank you again.